# Adobe flex can't load module using ModuleLoader

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxmlc

Main.swf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- modules/StyleModLoaderApp.mxml -->
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:layout> 
        <s:VerticalLayout/> 
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";

        s|Button { 
            color:blue;
            cornerRadius:10;
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:ModuleLoader id="ml1" url="mod1.swf"/>
    </s:VGroup>

    <s:Button id="myButton" label="Main App Button"/>

</s:Application>
```

mod1.swf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Style>
        @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
        s|Button { 
            color:red;
        }
    </fx:Style>

    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label id="lab1" text="Module 1"/>
         <s:Button id="myButton1" label="mod1 button"/>
    </s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Why can this happening?

both the Main.swf and the mod1.swf are in the same folder, the Main.swf executes fine, but there are no mod1.swf button, that should be loaded, dwadwadwafeaf

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What events are firing?

Comment: what events?, in the console there are no errors, but the module don't show, can you try this code?, or how do you load modules?

Comment: Check the docs for the events ModuleLoader dispatches and listen for them. That should give you a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: In the Application file, use an <s:ModuleLoader> tag to load each of the modules, that is said in the docs, so there is no need to call some events, it should be loaded automatically, if the tag ModuleLoader is there, and the swf file exists, i can't understand why that is not happening

Comment: Seems to me that you try to load a 'sub application' and not a module. A module is based normally on the Module class, your swf you try to load is based on 'Application'. To load sub application use the SWFLoader class

Comment: please can you give a little code example of the main app, and the module swf, i've readed the docs, but the example from there don't work to me

Comment: Then it is time to sharpen up your debugging skills, which means looking to see what events are firing during the process (hint, there is probably an error event being dispatched that you are not receiving because you are not listening).

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the Application tag to Module in the `mod1.swf`. Module loader will not be able to handle Application tagged `swf`.